# How to compare uint8_t array to a string in C?

Tags: c, string, uint8t

I have an input which comes over UART.

```
uint8_t uartRX_data[UART_RX_BUF_SIZE]="";
```

I need to pass this data to a function. And, in this function I want to compare it with predefined strings like:

```
char RESP_OK[]                  = "OK";
char RESP_ERROR[]               = "ERROR";
char RESP_FAIL[]                = "FAIL";
```

What is the easiest way to do that?

EDIT: My problem is only about the data comparison and data passing to a function.

Comment: Is the data in `uartRX_data` terminated with a NUL (`'\0'`) character or does a separate variable tell the number of valid bytes in the buffer? If the buffer is not terminated with a NUL (`'\0'`) character, does it have space to add one? Please [edit] your question to add information.

Comment: 'uartRX_data' is not the original data of buffer. I'm parsing the original data under an event handler to create 'uartRX_data' . The data is not terminated  with a NUL. It only includes characters.

Comment: So a non separated array of chars? Will this array include additional substrings than the 3 you've listed above?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information. How do you know how many characters are valid in `uartRX_data`? Is there a variable that contains the number of characters? Does the buffer have space to add a NUL?

Comment: I understood your question. You can assume that the array is terminated with a NUL character. It's my fault, sorry.

Comment: Then just `strcmp((const char *)uartRX_data, RESP_OK)` and so on should work.

Comment: @simon It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the string in `uartRX_data` is NULL terminated you should be able to use `strcmp` like so:

```
if (strcmp((const char *)uartRX_data, RESP_OK) == 0)
{
  // handle OK
}
else if (strcmp((const char *)uartRX_data, RESP_ERROR) == 0)
{
  // handle ERROR
}
else if (strcmp((const char *)uartRX_data, RESP_FAIL) == 0)
{
  // handle FAIL
}
else
{
  // handle unknown response
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most conversions between the types `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `int8_t` and `uint8_t` can be regarded as safe. These are *the character types* and come with various special exceptions that make them more "rugged" than other types.

Specifically, the character types:

- Cannot be misaligned.
- Cannot contain padding bits or trap representations.
- Have exceptions from the effective type/strict aliasing rules.
- Are always of size 1 byte.

Meaning you can do all manner of wild conversions between different character types. With a few exceptions:

- When going from unsigned to signed types the data may not necessarily fit and you'll overwrite the sign bit. This will potentially cause bugs.
- It is dangerous to "cast away" `const` or `volatile` qualifiers, if present.

Therefore it is safe to convert from `uint8_t*` to `char*` and de-reference the data as another type, `(char*)uartRX_data`. Especially if you know that the `uint8_t` array contains valid 7 bit characters only with MSB never set, and with a null termination in the end of the array.