# Get index of a specific string in string array which is defined as uint8

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have the following case:

An array is defined as an unsigned integer:

```
uint8 myArray[6][10] = {"continent","country","city","address", "street", "number"};
```

Now I want to get for example the index of the string "city". I imagine to do something like this:

```
uint8 idx;

for(idx = 0; idx < sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0];i++))
{
    if((myArray[idx]) == "city")   // This can not work because the array is an uint8 array
    {
         /*idx = 2 ....*/
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to do it without using functions from string.h like strcpy etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings)

Comment: You may have a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/q/55967430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by others you can not compare two C strings with the equal operator `=`, instead you need to use `strcmp`, and since you are not allowed to use it you need to implement it yourself.

Here the implementation of [strcmp in glibc](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strcmp.c.html)

So your code can be something like:

```
int mystrcmp(const uint8 *s1, const uint8 *s2)
{
    uint8 c1, c2;
    do
    {
        c1 = *s1++;
        c2 = *s2++;
        if (c1 == '\0')
            return c1 - c2;
    }
    while (c1 == c2);
    return c1 - c2;
}
....
uint8 *str = "city";
size_t size = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]);
size_t idx;

for (idx = 0; idx < size; i++)
{
    if (mystrcmp(myArray[idx], str) == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
if (idx == size)
{
    printf("'%s' was not found\n", str);
}
else
{
    printf("'%s' was found at index %zu\n", str, idx);
}
```

Comment: This solution works fine! But how to solve the compiler warning: "pointers to different types at assignment" on line uint8 *str = "city"; ?

Comment: Use a cast: `uint8 *str = (uint8 *)"city";`

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the strings character-by-character.

For this you write a loop going from the first character until it finds an unmatched character or an end-of-string marker in either string, what ever comes first.